# Appended array element not populating with data

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not sure what's happening here. I am trying to build an array by appending an element to the end of it. The element I am trying to append is another array. The base array, `$array` is in a loop, so I am expecting to see all of the `cid` data appended to `$array`, but all I am getting is one value and nothing more. If I can echo all of the values belonging to `cid` then why am I only getting a single value?

This is what the code looks like. I want to append `unlink` with another the `cid` array as the value.

The strange thing is that the `foo` array works. I don't understand why I can't get the `cid` array with all the values to append to the `$array`.

```
foreach( $hash as $tmp ){
    $array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ] = array(
      'file' => $pieces['filename']
    );

    if( $attr['Checked'] == 0 ) {
        $array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]['retain'] = $pieces['filename'];
    }else{
          // $foo[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]['unlink'][ ] = $tmp['cid'];
        $array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]['unlink'][ ] = $tmp['cid'];
    }
}
```

The array should look like this when complete

```
Array(
    [file] => some value
    [retain] => another value
    [unlink] => array
    (
        [0] => 1111
        [1] => 2222
        ....
    )
)
```

EDIT:

To clarify, the `$array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]` build just fine with all of the correct values. The problem that I'm having is with the `unlink` element that I'm attempting to append. The element appends to `$array` but I only see a single value instead of multiple array values.

```
Array(
    [file] => some value
    [retain] => another value
    [unlink] => array
    (
        [0] => 1111 <---- This is the issue. Only one value when there should me multiple values.
    )
)
```

Comment: Because everytime you overwrite `$array[ $grpIdx ]`?

Comment: You using arrays $hash, $pieces, $attr, variable $grpIdx. Where you define its? Or show its values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `$array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]` already exists

```
foreach( $hash as $tmp ){

    if (!isset($array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]) {
        $array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ] = array(
          'file' => $pieces['filename']
        );
    }

    if( $attr['Checked'] == 0 ) {
        $array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]['retain'] = $pieces['filename'];
    }else{
        // $foo[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]['unlink'][ ] = $tmp['cid'];
        $array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]['unlink'][ ] = $tmp['cid'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is not totally clear, my suggestion is that you overwrite `$array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]` on every iteration. You should add a check:

```
if (empty($array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ])) {
    $array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ] = array(
      'file' => $pieces['filename']
    );
}
```

In this case you will create `$array[ $grpIdx ][ $tmp['iid'] ]` only **once** for each `$tmp['iid']`.

Comment: I just added that check and I'm still not seeing the values, but rather a single value. I'm sure the `cid` array is being overwritten but I don't see where.